# jenkins root package name change by xmlrunner

Tags: python, jenkins

I'm using xmlrunner module for python to generate report in xml format for jenkins. And xml output will list the classname & testcase name :

testcase classname="FunctionalTest" name="test_1_1_1_1FunctionalCheck" time="1.43

This xml output will be listed under root package in Jenkins.

Something like this in Jenkins:
/root/FunctionalTest

How can i change the root package name in Jenkins , as i want the results to be listed by the classname.

Is there a way to modify the root name by ?